# share requirements.txt across projects

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

Maybe I'm approaching it in the wrong way, but I'm trying to keep packages in-sync across 2 separate GitHub projects. They share some dependencies, and they keep going out of sync (due to frequent updates to `botocore`, `boto3`, `awscli`)

It's fine (great, actually), if the `requirements.txt` in `Project B` could reflect whatever is in `origin master` on `Project A`

I was hoping to do something like:

```
# Project A, aws-requirements.txt
awscli==1.2.3
boto==4.5.6
boto3==7.8.9
```

and then:

```
# Project B, requirements.txt
-r https://github.com/me/project-a/blob/master/aws-requirements.txt
# etc, etc
```

But when I try running `pip install -r requirements.txt` in `Project B`, I get the error:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: 404 Client 
Error: Not Found for url: https://github.com/me/project-a/blob/master/requirements-dev.txt
```

So that appears to *not* be the way to do this. Is there a way to easily share `requirements.txt` across projects?

Comment: First of all, I assume you need to look at the raw text file instead of the github page. Click the "Raw" button on the text file in Github: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/project-a/blob/master/aws-requirements.txt`

Comment: Oh, right, that's one obvious issue... :) - edit, aaaand that was it! Feel free to post as an answer and I'll accept. Thanks!